# Convert GMT to IST in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert GMT to IST in snowflakes. I converted but when I try to change DateTime to date then it is not working.

SELECT '2020-02-29 23:59:57' AS Date,
convert_timezone('UTC', '2020-02-29 23:59:57')  IST_datetime,
cast(convert_timezone('UTC', '2020-02-29 23:59:57') AS date) IST_date

```
 DATE                  IST_DATETIME         IST_DATE
```

2020-02-29 23:59:57     2020-03-01 05:29:57    **2020-02-29**

[Problem is highlighted in red rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EYwe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of date, use datetime:

```
SELECT '2020-02-29 23:59:57' AS Date, 
convert_timezone('GMT','Asia/Kolkata', '2020-02-29 23:59:57') IST_datetime,
cast(convert_timezone('GMT','Asia/Kolkata', '2020-02-29 23:59:57') AS datetime) IST_date;
```

By the way, I also added source and target timezone (GMT/Kolkata) for reliable conversion (which will be not depend on your session timezone).